# Trouble with binary search function

Tags: c++, binary-search

No matter what value I search for, the program says it is not found in the file. I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

```
     int main()
    {
        int array1[MAX_NUMBER];
        int length;
        int number;
        int location;

        input (array1, MAX_NUMBER, length);

        cout<<"Please enter a number to search for:"<<endl;
        cin>>number;

        location=search(array1, length, number);

        if (location!=-1)
        {
            cout<<"The number "<<number<<" was found in the "<<location<<" position."<<endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout<<"The number "<<number<<" was not found in the file."<<endl;
        }




        return 0;
    }

void input(int a[], int size, int& number_used)
{
    ifstream infile;
    int input;

    infile.open("numbers.txt");

    if (infile.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Input file opening failed."<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int i;


    for (i=0; i<=size; i++)
    {
        while (infile>>input)
        {

            a[i]=input;
            cout<<a[i]<<endl;

        }
    }

    number_used=i;

}

int search(const int a[], int number_used, int search_value)
{
    int start=1;
    int end=number_used;
    int key=search_value;

    while (start<=end)
    {
        int mid=((start+end)/2);

        if (a[mid]==key)
        {
            return mid;
        }

        if (a[mid]>key)
        {
            end=mid-1;
        }

        else 
        {
            start=mid+1;
        }

    }
        return -1;


}
```

Is my problem in the main code or in the search function?

Input file:

```
1
5
6
7
11
19
21
23
33
54
78
97
```

For instance, typing 19, the output is "The number 19 was not found in the file."

Comment: Your problem is that you are not using a debugger

Answer (score 2):

You're not filling the array correct in function `input`.
You must use another index to store values in array, otherwise `i` will not indicate a valid and meaningful index in `a` :

```
int k = 0; // <-------------------------- 

int i;
for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
{
    while (infile >> input && k < size)
    {

        a[k] = input; // <----------------

        k++;  // <----------------
    }
}

number_used = k; // <-------------
```

And, as WhozCraig commented, you should know arrays start from `0` not `1` therefore in `search` method:

```
int start = 0;
```

Comment: +1 and the search function will never find the value in the [0] slot if searched for. There are several things wrong with this code, the initialization being the most glaring. Someone needs a refresher on 0-based indexing. (and time on the business-end of a line-debugger).

Comment: This code could still put more values into `a` if `k` becomes larger than `size`. You're always indexing using `k`, but you only do size checks on `i`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not computing the length of the list of values that you read in correctly. You have a loop inside of a loop, and it's doing something weird.

What you should be doing is something more like:

```
int i;

while (i < size && infile >> input)
{
    a[i]=input;
    cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    i++;
}

number_used=i;
```

Comment: @iamthewalrus Now try searching for the value `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Binary searches require that the array is already sorted. Try your algorithm by hand: find the number 4 in [4, 1, 3, 6, 5]. 4 is greater than the middle element, so the algorithm will go to the [4, 6, 5] portion of the array.

Comment: The array is already sorted, though. Also, your example is a bit strange.